# Security precautions and techniques for a User-submitted Code Demo Area

Tags: php, javascript, security, codeigniter, xss

Maybe this isn't really feasible. But basically, I've been developing a snippet-sharing website and I would like it to have a 'live demo area'.

For example, you're browsing some snippets and click the Demo button. A new window pops up which executes the web code.

I understand there are a gazillion security risks involved in doing this - XSS,  tags, nasty malware/drive by downloads, pr0n, etc. etc. etc.

The community would be able to flag submissions that are blatantly naughty but obviously some would go undetected (and, in many cases, someone would have to fall victim to discover whatever nasty thing was submitted).

So I need to know:
**What should I do - security wise - to make sure that users can submit code, but that nothing malicious can be run - or executed offsite, etc?**

For your information my site is powered by PHP using CodeIgniter.

Jack

Comment: Are the snippets going to be exclusively Javascript?

Comment: If you want real security, you'll have to develop a technique for whitelisting code you know is "safe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frank pointed out, if you want to maintain a high level of security use a whitelist technique. This of course comes with a price (might be too restrictive, hard to implement).

The alternative route is to develop a blacklist technique. i.e. only allow code that hasn't triggered any bells. This is easier, because you have to specify less things, but it will not catch new exploits.

There is plenty information available on the web on both techniques.

Relying on CodeIgniters security functions (XSS filtering etc.) will not get you very far as most of the snippets will not be allowed through.

Whatever you do you have to remember this:

Do not think malicious code will aim to just harm your website's visitors. It may as well aim to compromise your server via your parser/code inspector. For example, lets say Alice uploads snippet foo. Alice intentionally crafts the snippet so that your parser will flag it as malicious due to an XSS exploit. Lets say your parser also updates a database with the malicious snippet for further investigation. Alice knows this. Along with the XSS exploit Alice has injected some SQL code in the snippet, so that when you INSERT the snippet to the database it will do all sorts of bad stuff.

If you are really paranoid, you could have an isolated server which its solely responsibility would be to inspect code snippets. So in the WCS only that low-risk server would be compromised, and you would have (hopefully) enough time to fix/audit the situation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot whitelist or blacklist PHP, it just doesn't work. If you write up a list of commands that I can use, or stop me from using malicious functions, what is to stop me from writing:

```
$a = 'mai';

{$a .'l'}('somebody@important.com', 'You suck', 'A dodgy message sent from your server');
```

**You cannot whitelist or blacklist PHP.**

Answer (score 0):

> For your information my site is powered by PHP using CodeIgniter

Sorry Jack, if you think that is in the least bit relevant you're a very long way from understanding any valid answer to the question - let alone being able to distinguish the invalid ones.

Any sandbox you create which will prevent someone from attacking your machine or your customers will be so restrictive that your clients will not be able to do much more than 'print'.

You'd need to run a CLI version of suhosin on a custom chroot jail - and maintianing seperate environments for every script would be totally impractical.

C.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are only allowing javascript code, then you should do the following -

1. Purchase a throw-away domain name that is not identifiable with your domain
2. Serve the user-entered code in an iframe that is hosted from the throw-away domain

This is essentially what iGoogle does. It prevents XSS because you are using a different domain. The only loophole I am aware of is that evil code can change the location of the webpage.

If you intend to share snippets of server side code, then it is a different ballgame. For java/jsp snippets, you could use JVMs internal Security classes to run the code in a sandbox. You should find a lot of information on this if you google. I would like to think this is what google uses in App Engine (I am not sure though).

Anything other than Java, I am not sure how to protect. Dot Net perhaps has a similar concept, but I doubt you could sandbox PHP code snippets in a similar manner.